# How to generate xml attribute value from another xml without hardcoding usinf xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I saw an example to transform xml to another xml using JSTL. But in that example they hard coded the attribute value. Please see the bellow example

**Input XML**

```
country isocode="de" pk="8796093055010" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de">
        <comments/>
        <creationtime>2011-08-03T21:53:35.624+05:30</creationtime>
        <dimVals/>
        <modifiedtime>2011-08-03T22:05:10.111+05:30</modifiedtime>
        <active>true</active>
        <name>Germany</name>
        <regions>
              <region isocode="DE-BW" pk="8796093055011" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BW"/>
              <region isocode="DE-BY" pk="8796093087779" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BY"/>
              <region isocode="DE-BE" pk="8796093120547" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BE"/>
              <region isocode="DE-BR" pk="8796093153315" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BR"/>
              <region isocode="DE-HB" pk="8796093186083" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HB"/>
              <region isocode="DE-HH" pk="8796093218851" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HH"/>
              <region isocode="DE-HE" pk="8796093251619" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HE"/>
              <region isocode="DE-MV" pk="8796093284387" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-MV"/>
              <region isocode="DE-NI" pk="8796093317155" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-NI"/>
              <region isocode="DE-NW" pk="8796093349923" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-NW"/>
              <region isocode="DE-RP" pk="8796093382691" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-RP"/>
              <region isocode="DE-SL" pk="8796093415459" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SL"/>
              <region isocode="DE-ST" pk="8796093448227" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-ST"/>
              <region isocode="DE-SN" pk="8796093480995" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SN"/>
              <region isocode="DE-SH" pk="8796093513763" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SH"/>
              <region isocode="DE-TH" pk="8796093546531" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-TH"/>
        </regions>
        <zones>
            <zone code="de" pk="8796093056179" uri="http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/zones/de"/>
        </zones>
</country>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/country/regions" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="regions">
        <RECORDS>
            <xsl:for-each select="region">
                <RECORD>
                    <PROP name="isocode">
                        <PVAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@isocode" />
                        </PVAL>
                    </PROP>
                    <PROP name="pk">
                        <PVAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@pk" />
                        </PVAL>
                    </PROP>
                    <PROP name="uri">
                        <PVAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@uri" />
                        </PVAL>
                    </PROP>
                </RECORD>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RECORDS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-BW</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093055011</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BW</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-BY</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093087779</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BY</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-BE</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093120547</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BE</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-BR</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093153315</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BR</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-HB</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093186083</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HB</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-HH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093218851</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-HE</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093251619</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-HE</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-MV</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093284387</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-MV</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-NI</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093317155</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-NI</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-NW</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093349923</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-NW</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-RP</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093382691</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-RP</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-SL</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093415459</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SL</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-ST</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093448227</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-ST</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-SN</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093480995</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SN</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-SH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093513763</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-SH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PROP name="isocode">
            <PVAL>DE-TH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="pk">
            <PVAL>8796093546531</PVAL>
        </PROP>
        <PROP name="uri">
            <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-TH</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

In this output xml I am creating many RECORD sub elements. My problem is I want to transform the PROB name attribute () value without hardcoding. I need to read the **reagion** element attributtes from input xml and transform that value to output xml. Please help me to find the solution. 
 Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/country/regions" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="regions">
    <RECORDS>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="region" />
    </RECORDS>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="region">
    <RECORD>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </RECORD>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="region/@*">
    <PROP name="{name()}">
      <PVAL>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your input XML, this produces the output:

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP name="isocode">
      <PVAL>DE-BW</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP name="pk">
      <PVAL>8796093055011</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP name="uri">
      <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BW</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP name="isocode">
      <PVAL>DE-BY</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP name="pk">
      <PVAL>8796093087779</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP name="uri">
      <PVAL>http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries/de/regions/DE-BY</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
  <!-- (Several more similar records) -->
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: Yes. This is the one I want to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1586908 Great.  You're welcome. If it works, please remember to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it. Thanks!